# Creating a mongodb query in Java with $or and $in

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, query-builder, mongodb-java

I am trying to write a java code using mongodb api to create this mongodb query:

```
{ "$or": [{"prd" : {"$in" : ["1234", "0987"]}} , {"rsin" : "3228742"}]}
```

Here's the code I am working with so far:

```
QueryBuilder builder = new QueryBuilder();

if (builder == null) {
    builder = QueryBuilder.start();
 }

if (mongoKey.equals("prd")){

     ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();

     for (int i=0; i < prdList; i++){
         vals.add(prdList.get(i));
     }

     DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject (mongoKey, new BasicDBObject("$in", vals));
     builder.or(obj);

}else {
      builder.and(mongoKey).is(mongoValue);
}
```

This is currently printing out the wrong syntax:

```
{ "$or": [{"prd" : {"$in" : ["1234", "0987"]}}] , "rsin" : "3228742"}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on `else` block, you need to use `or` method instead of `and`.

```
...
}else {
    builder.or(new BasicDBObject(mongoKey, mongoValue));
}
```

This will produce the query that you want.