# How to use "$or" operator using documents in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
Document query = new Document();
            query.put("firstName", "abc");
            query.put("firstName", "xyz");
```

Here,"abc" is overrided by the "xyz".So,in the query I'm getting only one value i.e,xyz.I don't know,why the query getting overrided.can u please help me out...

My code:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("sample");
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("users");


        Document query = new Document();
        query.put("firstName", "abc");
        query.put("firstName", "xyz");

        Document docStatus =new Document("$or",query );
        try (MongoCursor<Document> cursor = coll.find(query).iterator()) {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a mongodb query in Java with $or and $in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561587/creating-a-mongodb-query-in-java-with-or-and-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator are a `List`, therefore you are just contructing a `List` of `Document`:

```
Document query = new Document(
  "$or", Arrays.asList(
    new Document("firstname", "abc"),
    new Document("firstname", "xyz")
  )
)
```

But really, when you want an `$or` condition on the same property, use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) instead. Which is of course another `List` but just of values:

```
Document query = new Document(
    "firstname",
    new Document(
        "$in", Arrays.asList("abc","xyz")
    )
)
```

Which is much shorter syntax for the selection of "either" value on the same document property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct your query as below :

```
DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("firstName", "abc");  
DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("firstName", "xyz");    
BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
or.add(clause1);
or.add(clause2);
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
```

Answer (score 0):

BasicDBList orList = new BasicDBList();

orList.add(new BasicDBObject("FirstName","xxx"));

orList.add(new BasicDBObject("LastName","yyy"));

BasicDBObject dbObj = new BasicDBObject("$or",orList);